# adding just business days to a calculated field in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Is there an expression I can use to add just business days (no holidays) to a date in another field?

For example:  a field contains a date a hearing was held. The decision is due 5 business days (+ no holidays) from that date. I would like to have another field where the deadline date will be automatically populated into that field.  I don't program and would like to use an expression that can be put in the "click to add" column at the far right of the table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an expression I can use to add just business days (no holidays) to a date in another field?

A simple Access SQL/VBA expression? No, because holidays can be different depending on the jurisdiction (e.g., country) you are in. The most common solution is to use a "holiday table" or a "calendar table" with a Yes/No field for the holidays that are observed in your particular case.